# Imitating iOS slide animations with velocityjs

Tags: cordova, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations, velocity.js

I am building a mobile application with phonegap, and trying to imitate iphone's slide animations using `velocityjs`. I tried all durations (200,300,400,500...) but they don't seem perfect to me. I assume I should use some `ease` function.

Q. How can you simulate iPhone's slide animations with velocityjs?

Bonus Q. How about for Android?

Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: I am guessing you already have seen the **[examples](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#fade)**?

Comment: Is there a specific example how to exactly imitate mobile slide animations?

Comment: Can you share your code of what you have tried please?